# Generic parameter in NHibernate Linq query

Tags: .net, linq, nhibernate, generics, linq-to-nhibernate

Is there any way to compare generic types in linq query to translate to SQL with NHibernate?

Something like this:

```cs
public abstract class DataProviderBase<TDAO, TId>
{
    protected ISession Session;

    public virtual TDAO GetById(TId id)
    {
        var allItems = GetAllQuery();  // gives me query, usually Session.Query<TDAO>();
        var res = allItems.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
            // !!! Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TId' and 'TId'
        return res;
    }

    protected virtual IQueryable<TDAO> GetAllQuery()
    {
        var query = Session.Query<TDAO>();
        return query;
    }
}
```

I know I can use `Session.Get<TDAO>(id);`, but that is not what I am going for. `GetAllQuery()` is a virtual method and i want to be able to override it.

- **NHibernate** version: 3.3.3.4000
- **NHibernate.Linq** version: 1.0

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `item.Id.Equals(id)`?

Comment: Yes I have, it throws: `System.NotSupportedException : Boolean Equals(System.Object)`

Comment: @MartinVolek this might be part of the problem or not, but NHibernate.Linq is to be used with NH 2.1.2; NH 3+ has an integrated Linq provider. Make sure you are NOT using the old package.

Comment: @Diego Mijelshon I did not know that. I have removed the Nhibernate.Linq assembly but it did not help as I expected. I have not been using it before. But good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your predicate dinamically. For example:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TDAO));
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TDAO, bool>>(
    Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "Id"),
                     Expression.Constant(id)),
    parameter);
var res = allItems.SingleOrDefault(predicate);
```